# How do I change a label's text to a file name on button press in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I change the text of `label_1` to equal the file I select in `browse_for_file_1`? I've been trying various methods but I just can't seem to get the GUI to update. I think it may be because it's in a frame within a frame?

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog

root = tk.Tk()

#Frames
frame_1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame_1.pack()

def browse_for_file_1():
    file_name_1 = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,title='Open 1st File')
    print file_name_1
    label_1.config(text=file_name_1)
    root.update()



#Browse 1
browse_button_1 = tk.Button(frame_1, text='Browse for 1st File', width=25, command=browse_for_file_1).pack(side=tk.LEFT, pady=10, padx=10)
label_1 = tk.Label(frame_1, fg="red", text="No file selected.")
label_1.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, pady=10, padx=10)

#Quit Button
quit = tk.Button(root, text='QUIT', width=25, fg="red", command=root.destroy).pack(pady=10, padx=10)

root.title("Zero Usage")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have been clearer. First of all I tried a `textvariable` for the label text. Then I attempted `label_1.config(text='Example')` and `root.update()` after each of these. 

Yes, absolutely nothing happens. No errors but it clearly doesn't work.

Comment: This is the minimal example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your call:

`browse_button_1 = tk.Button(frame_1, text='Browse for 1st File', width=25, command=lambda:browse_for_file_1(label_1)).pack(side=tk.LEFT, pady=10, padx=10)`

Then your function can be:

```
def browse_for_file_1(label_1):
  file_name_1 = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,title='Open 1st File')
  label_1.config(text=file_name_1)
  # or label_1.config({'text':file_name_1})
```